# Misunderstanding Regarding Equal Probability

Tags: statistical-mechanics

Reading through Pathria for stat mech and I am struggling with the notation of "equal a prior probabilities" for all microstates consistent with a given macrostate. In principle, I understand this idea, but I'm doing something weird in the mathematics of it. Abbreviating the derivation from Pathria, with two systems in thermal contact, exchanging energy, but neither N or V, we get,
$$\frac{\partial \ln \Omega(\bar{E})}{\partial E} \equiv\beta \tag{1}$$
Assuming a reversible process and holding N, V constant,
$$\frac{\partial S}{\partial E}=\frac{1}{T} \tag{2}$$
Dividing (2) by (1) and approximating with non-infinitesimal changes,
$$\frac{\Delta S}{\Delta \ln \Omega} =\frac{1}{\beta T} = k_B \tag{3}$$
And assuming no constant $S_0$,
$$S=k_B \ln \Omega \tag{4}$$
Now if we apply our "equal probability" postulate,
$$\rho=1/\Omega\tag{5}$$
Then we get,
$$S=-k_B \ln \rho$$
If I assign the state function, $\bar{E}=F+ST$, we pretty easily get back to the canonical ensemble, namely,
$$\rho(\bar{E})=e^{(F-\bar{E})/kT} \tag{6}$$
Which clearly gives higher probability for lower energies. It seems to be in conflict with (5).

Where have I gone wrong?

Comment: $\Omega$ depends on energy, in fact it is a monotonically increasing function of $\bar{E}$ if the temperature is positive [see Eq. (1)]. Where's the conflict?

Comment: When I see a plot of (6) it seems to me the probabilities aren't equal. Yet the first postulate is that they are equal. I know I'm misunderstanding something here I just haven't grasped it

Comment: As you say: one assumes equal a priori probabilities *for all microstates consistent with a given macrostate*. For the microcanonical ensemble, the relevant macrostate is $(E,N,V)$. For the canonical ensemble, it is $(T,N,V)$ and, for this ensemble, equiprobability does not hold.

Comment: @YvanVelenik Okay I'm smacking myself a bit now. So the microcanonical ensemble can be two systems that share energy, or other mechanical variables, (e.g. E is the fundamental quantity in question), and in the canonical ensemble it's a system and a heat bath (T is the fundamental quantity in question)

Comment: Yes, that's exactly right.